# android OpenGL error from eglCreatePbufferSurface

Tags: android, opengl-es

I made android camera app and I need to use Pbuffer for rendering captured 
image.

I got a crash when initialize OpenGL.

Actually This crash occur when Users use my app, I got this messages from Fabric

So, I can't reproduce a crash... and don't know why it happen

Maybe I did something wrong.

Please review my code

```
private void initGL(int width, int height) {
    egl10 = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();

    eglDisplay = egl10.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (eglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglGetDisplay failed " +
                android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
    }

    int[] version = new int[2];
    if (!egl10.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglInitialize failed " +
                android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
    }

    int[] configsCount = new int[1];
    EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
    int[] configSpec = {
            EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
            EGL10.EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
            EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
            EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
            EGL10.EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLConfig eglConfig = null;
    if (!egl10.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configSpec, configs, 1, configsCount)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("eglChooseConfig failed " +
                android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
    } else if (configsCount[0] > 0) {
        eglConfig = configs[0];
    }
    if (eglConfig == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglConfig not initialized");
    }

    int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE};
    eglContext = egl10.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);

    int[] surfaceAttr = {
            EGL10.EGL_WIDTH, width,
            EGL10.EGL_HEIGHT, height,
            EGL10.EGL_NONE
    };
    eglSurface = egl10.eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, surfaceAttr);

    if (eglSurface == null || eglSurface == EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglCreatePbufferSurface failed " +
                android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
    }

    if (!egl10.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed " +
                android.opengl.GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl10.eglGetError()));
    }
}
```

And this is error messa

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: eglCreatePbufferSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
   at com.teambartender3.filters.FilterableCamera.FCameraCapture.initGL(FCameraCapture.java:307)
   at com.teambartender3.filters.FilterableCamera.FCameraCapture.access$200(FCameraCapture.java:48)
   at com.teambartender3.filters.FilterableCamera.FCameraCapture$1.run(FCameraCapture.java:141)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

If you want to review full version of my code, you can visit my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/gmlwhdtjd/Filters)

Answer (score 0):

... and the specification says ...

https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreatePbufferSurface.xhtml

> `EGL_BAD_ALLOC` is generated if there are not enough resources to
>   allocate the new surface.

Basically, you're not gracefully handling out-of-memory scenarios.

Comment: I think so too. Could you explain how can I start to fix this scenario? I think, I need some limitation for low end devices. Is that right?